# Не запускается python скрипт через exec в php

Tags: php

Нужна помощь. Пытаюсь запустить скрипт python через кнопку на сайте(скрипт меняет текст в docx фале. скрипт не взаимодействует с пользователем).

```
<form action="index-php.php" method="post">
    <p><b>Отправить</b><br>
    <input type="submit" name="save" >
</form>

//index-php.php:
$pylaunch = exec('py/index.py' );
```

После нажатия ошибки нет, но и код не работает. В терминале выводит:

> Unable to create process using
> 'C:\Users\olegu\Desktop\md\pyt\python.exe /index.py': ?? ??????? ?????
> ????????? ????.

Comment: Написав в консоль "py/index.py" что нибудь выполнится? Нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
 <form action="index-php.php">
 <p><b>Отправить</b><br>
 <input type="submit" name="save" >
 </form>
```

PHP

```
$pylaunch = exec('python py/index.py');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php